# Android GridLayout layout_columnWeight="1" and layout_width="0dp" programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin, grid-layout

I use GridLayout and want to add View programmatically.

I want all view evenly divided but get some problem.

My problem:(`600` width and `700` width are not equals)
[image]

I want :

[image]

xml:

```
  <GridLayout
                        android:id="@+id/withdrawSettingLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:useDefaultMargins="true"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:columnCount="4"/>
```

Kotlin code:

```
list.forEach { amount->

    val titleText = TextView(context).apply {
        text = amount
        setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white))
    }
    val layoutParams = GridLayout.LayoutParams(GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1f), GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1f))
    layoutParams.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1f)
    viewBinding.withdrawSettingLayout.addView(titleText, layoutParams)
}
```

how to solve it, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using Linear Layout or Constraint Layout?

Comment: @TarsilaCostalonga Yes they can work but more complicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it helps, but you can try to also add:

```
layoutParams.width = 0
```

Comment: It works. Can't believe so simple, thanks!